# How to use "When" with any condition expression?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use when with one condition expression like this:

```
fun getStringLength(s: Int){
    when(s < 5){

    }
}
```

The code gets compiled but when i try to give the body to this when block like:

```
fun getStringLength(s: Int){
    when(s < 5){
       in 1..5 -> println("It is less than 5")
    }
}
```

It gives me an error of: "**Error:(13, 7) Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.
Error:(13, 7) Type mismatch: incompatible types of range and element checked in it**"

So how do i make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `s < 5` it is calculated to boolean value, that's why your conditions should be true, false or else.

```
fun getStringLength(s: Int){
    when(s < 5){
        true -> println("It is less than 5")
        false -> println("It is NOT less than 5")
    }
}
```

To use range in, please, try this one:

```
fun getStringLength(s: Int){
    when(s){
       in 1..5 -> println("It is less than 5")
    }
}
```

Comment: So its not able to compute the boolean expressions if write that way? We have to use in or !in to write like this?

Comment: @sak In other words, `s < 5` is a boolean and boolean cannot be `in 1..5`. Boolean is not an int, hence the compile error. Write maintainable code. This should be a simple if statement. You shouldn't have to go to stack overflow to figure out what could have been an if statement.

Comment: Its not a compile time error, i mean writing only s < 5 is not a compile time error, I am only looking for  a way to use this condition expression, that what we can do with this: when(s<5){...} , can we directly print the value of s or any other stuff

Comment: @EugenPechanec The way you have displayed is an alternate way that i know but not the answer of how to use this: when(s<5){...}

Comment: @sak You could use `true -> {...}`, `false -> {...}` or `else -> {...}`, as already mentioned in the answer. (I just added the code sample, for clarity.)